# Restart-Button throws Exception and i don't know how to fix it

Tags: java, javafx

this my first Question here and I am new to JavaFX. I programmed a little Game and I can't figure out how to get the restart-Button to work. Here is the shortened Code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Pane root = new Pane();
    private static Button btnNewGame = new Button( "Neues Spiel?" );
    private static Sprite player = new Sprite( getRandomNumberInts( 590, 1230 ), getRandomNumberInts( 50, 670 ), 40, 40, /*"player",*/ Color.BLUE );
    ...
    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle( long now ) {
            update();
        }
    };

    private Parent createContent() {

        root.setPrefSize( 1280, 720 );
        timer.start();
        nextLevel();
        return root;
    }

    private void nextLevel() {
            root.getChildren().add( player );
     ...
}

    private void update() {
            snake.moveToTarget();
            if ( snake.getBoundsInParent().intersects( player.getBoundsInParent() ) ) {
                player.dead = true;
                player.win = false;
                }

                if( player.dead ) {
                    root.getChildren().add( btnNewGame );
                    root.getChildren().clear();
                    timer.stop();

                }

                if( player.win ) {
                    root.getChildren().add( btnNewGame );
                    root.getChildren().clear();
                    timer.stop();

                }

                root.getChildren().removeIf( n -> {
                    Sprite s = ( Sprite ) n;
                    return s.dead;
                });
    }

    void cleanup() {
        timer.stop();
        root.getChildren().clear();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    public void startGame( Stage stage ) {
            Scene scene = new Scene( createContent() );
            scene.setOnKeyPressed( e -> {
                switch ( e.getCode() ) {
                case W:

            });

            btnNewGame.setOnAction( e -> {              
                   restart( stage );                   
                });

            stage.setScene( scene );            
            stage.setTitle( "ZZZZZnake - Von Christoph Gabauer" );          
            stage.getIcons().add( new Image( Main.class.getResourceAsStream( "icon.png" ) ) );          
            stage.setResizable( false );            
            stage.show();           
    }

    void restart( Stage stage ) {       
        cleanup();      
        start( stage );     
    }

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) {       
        startGame( primaryStage );
    }

    private static class Sprite extends Rectangle {         
        //final String type;        
        double pSpeed = 5;      

        Sprite( int x, int y, int w, int h, /*String type,*/ Color color ){         
            super( w, h, color );           
            //this.type = type;         
            setTranslateX( x );         
            setTranslateY( y );
```

There are a few German Bits in there but don't let that distract you from the Problem. I think the Exception has something to do with the start or upgrade Method.
This is the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.Button cannot be cast to application.Main$Sprite
    at application.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:193)
    at java.util.Collection.removeIf(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.update(Main.java:191)
    at application.Main.access$0(Main.java:91)
    at application.Main$1.handle(Main.java:53)
    at javafx.animation.AnimationTimer$AnimationTimerReceiver.lambda$handle$0(AnimationTimer.java:57)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.animation.AnimationTimer$AnimationTimerReceiver.handle(AnimationTimer.java:56)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractMasterTimer.java:357)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractMasterTimer.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:557)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:541)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:534)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:340)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The goal would be that when you click the Button the Game restarts and acts the same as before.
I hope you can help me with my problem and thank you in advance.

Greetings from Bavaria

Christoph

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you pinpoint the line that throws the exception exactly?

Comment: [mcve] please .. that is _not_ a big heap of mostly unrelated code - instead, distill out the barest minimum to demonstrate the problem :)

Comment: -> stack overflow [survival guide](https://curiosag.github.io/StackOverflowStrategies/)

Comment: The problem is in the lambda `root.getChildren().removeIf( n -> {Sprite s = ( Sprite ) n; return s.dead;});`, you simply cast every child to `Sprite` but there are obviously elements that cannot be cast (because they are not `Sprite`s). That causes the exception.

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry i  will think about that in my next question!

Comment: you could edit your question and provide the example immediately :)

Comment: @kleopatra is it better now?

Comment: If your first problem was fixed, accept the answer. StackOverflow is not designed for dynamic questions. If you have a new problem ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `update` method:

```
root.getChildren().removeIf( n -> {
    Sprite s = (Sprite) n;
    return s.dead;
});
```

You simply assume all of the elements returned by `getChildren` are `Sprite`s, but the exception states that there is at least one `javafx.scene.control.Button` in there.

If you only want to remove dead sprites, use this:

```
root.getChildren().removeIf(n -> n instanceof Sprite && ((Sprite)n).dead);
```

As a hint for the future: learn to read stacktraces. Most of the time they tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks but now it says: `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pane@6269df8[styleClass=root]is already set as root of another scene` how do i fix that? Do i have to make a new Pane for it?